# Find inverse of a linear transormation given its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse-function

Let $T: R^2 \rightarrow R^2 $ (linear) with matrix  $A$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The basis isn't specified. The determinant of $A$ is $2$ , not $0$, so $A$ is invertible and thus $T$ is one-to-one ($T$ is an isomorphism), so there exists $T^{-1}$. How do we find $T^{-1}$?

Comment: You have already answered your own question

Comment: The inverse map is given by the inverse matrix. The better question is whether defining a linear map via a matrix makes sense if you do not know with respect to which basis it is defined. You may probably assume that it is defined w.r.t. the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the inverse of the matrix 
$ 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ is 
$ 
        \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix}
        d & -b \\
        -c & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$